# What is the best way to shift data by X bits into and out of a file?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a dataset, made up of a mask file, and a data file.
the mask file tells the decoder whether there are 8 bits per field present, or 4, for the current offset of the datafile.
I need to shift the data out according to the mask, and write the decoded file, with all 8 bits per field.
I'm trying to accomplish this in C.

```
void shift_4bits_left(unsigned char* array, unsigned short size)
{
int i;
unsigned char shifted = 0x00;    
unsigned char overflow = (0xF0 & array[0]) >> 4;

    for (i = (size - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
    shifted = (array[i] << 4) | overflow;
    overflow = (0xF0 & array[i]) >> 4;
    array[i] = shifted;
    }
}
```

in function:

```
while(len>count){
        //count=0;
        if(bit==0)yy=fread(blockchar,1,len,fp1);
        if(bit==0)memcpy(blockchar2,blockchar,len);
        count+=yy;
        memset(outputbuf,0,64);
        for(x=0;x<len;x++){
        count2=0;
        //count2=1;

        if(sometests(blockchar[x])==1)
        {
          shift_4bits_left(&blockchar[x],(yy-(bittest/2))+1);
          count2=1;
          total++;
          if(total%2==0)len--;
        }

//set bit for current position in mask file's buffer
        if((x)%8 == 0)outputbuf[x]+=(count2<<7);
        if((x)%8 == 1)outputbuf[x]+=(count2<<6);
        if((x)%8 == 2)outputbuf[x]+=(count2<<5);
        if((x)%8 == 3)outputbuf[x]+=(count2<<4);
        if((x)%8 == 4)outputbuf[x]+=(count2<<3);
        if((x)%8 == 5)outputbuf[x]+=(count2<<2);
        if((x)%8 == 6)outputbuf[x]+=(count2<<1);
        if((x)%8 == 7)outputbuf[x]+=count2;
        }
```

The problem is this is very slow when working with large datasets, I would prefer to make this iterative over the file, without storing the files in arrays.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you post what you have so far?

Comment: Rather than reading one byte/word at a time, read into a larger buffer - e.g. 4KB or something. Tracking which bits/bytes you're currently working on is a little more difficult that way, but the efficiency gains can be considerable.

Comment: I tried that, the performance actually got lower.

Comment: You could try `mmap`ping the file, and you could try to run the loop in the other direction, if you repeatedly jump ahead and then run back to where you jumped from, that can generate far more cache misses.

Comment: I dont know mmap from an egg sandwich. Example code would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please indent your code properly?

Comment: I would be able to if stackoverflow.com supported the [code] and [/code] bbcode elements...

Comment: Indents adjusted for ease on the coder eyesball

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by looking at 256 bytes at a time, and when not shifting, using memcpy. Thanks for the help guys.